# How to pass random value in Webdriver xpath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Need to select color swatch randomly by passing random value - my xpath for the color swatch is constructed like this - //*[@id='defaultSwatchContainer_wxnit']/div/div/ul/li[1] - 1 inside li tag goes up to 4. Requirement is to send any random number between 1-4 to li[], using following code but xpath is not taking external number, please advise.
Thanks

```
List list = new LinkedList(); 

      // populate list
      list.add(1);  
      list.add(2);  
      list.add(3);  
      list.add(4);
      Collections.shuffle(list);
    dd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='defaultSwatchContainer_wxnit']/div/div/ul/li[list]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='defaultSwatchContainer_wxnit']/div/div/ul/li["+ list.get(0)+"]")).click();
```

Right now your "list" is a string literal, you're just sending the text "list". You need to instead pull an element from list and add it to the string.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply but I figured out that parameter after "_" in this case which is "wxnit" changes with the page load & because of that unable to locate this element - think I need to use regular expression